# how to display a text for numeric values from database in datatable jsf

Tags: jsf, datatable

In a datatable column how can i display a text for a number value which is retrieved from database.

for eg if the value for a colum from database is 2 , then i need to display "Cheese" in datatable. similarly if the value is 3 then i need to display "cake".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to maintain a mapping of those values in the backing bean.

```
private Map<Long, String> foods;

public Bean() {
    foods = new HashMap<Long, String>();
    foods.put(1L, "Pizza");
    foods.put(2L, "Cheese");
    foods.put(3L, "Cake");
    // ...
}

public Map<Long, String> getFoods() { 
    return foods;
}
```

Then you can get it as follows

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{bean.foods[item.number]}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Where `#{item.number}` should return the desired number as `Long`.

Comment: @BalusC: Initially i was thinking of using messages.properties. is it possible to use the properties file for this purpose? Please let me know

Comment: You're welcome. Certainly, just replace `Map<Long, String>` by `Properties`. It'll work equally well since `Properties` extends `Map<Object, Object>`. The `#{item.number}` now doesn't necessarily need to be a `Long`. A `String` is also fine.

Comment: I will try to implement using properties also. thanks for your inputs.

Comment: @BalusC I tried to use properties.but having some issues.please help me.                                             messages.properties                                          1=cheese                                                            a= vannila                                                         in my xhtml file the following works                     <h:outputText value="#{msgs.a}"/> but not the following one <h:outputText value="#{msgs.1}"/>    also i need to substitute the value from database is this one fine? <h:outputText value="#{msgs[item.number]}"/>

Comment: For numbers, use this notation `#{msgs['1']}` and yes `#{msgs[item.number]}` should be fine.

Comment: thanks..it worked..is there any literature which tells about the notation to use for numbers..because before posting i searched but i couldnot find it in any book..

Comment: Let's say, you need 10 years experience to know about it.